# Pass a string with spaces as an argument to Bash function

Tags: bash

Given the following string variable

```
VAR="foo         bar"
```

I need it to be passed to a bash function, and accesses it, as usual, via `$1`.  So far I haven't been able to figure out how to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
function testfn(){
    echo "in function: $1"
}
VAR="foo         bar"
echo "desired output is:"
echo "$(testfn 'foo           bar')"
echo "Now, what about a version with \$VAR?"
echo "Note, by the way, that the following doesn't do the right thing:"
echo $(testfn "foo           bar") #prints: "in function: foo bar"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash is smart and pairs of double quotes match either inside or outside of a `$( ... )` structure.

Hence, `echo "$(testfn "foo         bar")"` is valid, and the result of your `testfn` function will only be considered as a single argument to the `echo` internal command.

Comment: Right on.  I was assuming that nested double quotes shouldn't be used, ever.  However, `echo "(testfn "$VAR")"` works just fine.